# xslt Distinct record fetching product

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**Input XML**

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductDetail>
            <ProductTitle>title1</ProductTitle>
        </ProductDetail>
        <Contact>
            <ContactHome>adad</ContactHome>
            <ContactInfo>
                <ContactNum>1</ContactNum>
                <ContactSINum>2</ContactSINum>
            </ContactInfo>
        </Contact>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductDetail>
            <ProductTitle>title2</ProductTitle>
        </ProductDetail>
        <Contact>
            <ContactHome/>
            <ContactInfo>
                <ContactNum>3</ContactNum>
                <ContactSINum>4</ContactSINum>
            </ContactInfo>
        </Contact>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductDetail>
            <ProductTitle>title1</ProductTitle>
        </ProductDetail>
        <Contact>
            <ContactHome/>
            <ContactInfo>
                <ContactNum>1</ContactNum>
                <ContactSINum>2</ContactSINum>
            </ContactInfo>
        </Contact>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Productcoll>
    <ProductINFO>
        <ProductTitle>title1</ProductTitle>
        <ContactNum>1</ContactNum>
        <ContactSINum>2</ContactSINum>
    </ProductINFO>
    <ProductINFO>
        <ProductTitle>title2</ProductTitle>
        <ContactNum>3</ContactNum>
        <ContactSINum>4</ContactSINum>
    </ProductINFO>
</Productcoll>
```

Tried with XSLT with using key and generate id. But....
How to use Key using nodes in different branches?

Comment: What's the logic? Are you trying to group by `ProductTitle`? Why are some elements excluded (like `ContactHome`)? What is supposed to happen if two elements have the same name, but different values? (Like `<ContactNum>1</ContactNum>` and `<ContactNum>2</ContactNum>` for the same `ProductTitle`.) Can you update your question with the XSLT that you tried?

Comment: Add code what you have tried and edit question to remove redundant text. The warning "mostly code" is set for a reason. Don't use dump text to fool the check. Be clear asking question with elaborate statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shared output, **it is assumed that the grouping has to be done on `<ProductTitle>`, `<ContactNum>` and `<ContactSINum>`** and only those values are to be extracted to the output XML.

A key can be defined by concatenating the values from the required nodes using a separator.

```
<xsl:key name="kProduct" match="Product"
        use="concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum)" />
```

Then loop through the `<Product>` nodes and get the first instance of the values grouped by the composite key.

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kProduct" match="Product"
        use="concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum)" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Products">
        <Productcoll>
            <xsl:for-each select="Product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kProduct', concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum))[1])]">
                <ProductINFO>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kProduct', concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum))[1]/ProductDetail/ProductTitle" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kProduct', concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum))[1]/Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kProduct', concat(ProductDetail/ProductTitle, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactNum, '|', Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum))[1]/Contact/ContactInfo/ContactSINum" />
                </ProductINFO>      
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Productcoll>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Productcoll>
   <ProductINFO>
      <ProductTitle>title1</ProductTitle>
      <ContactNum>1</ContactNum>
      <ContactSINum>2</ContactSINum>
   </ProductINFO>
   <ProductINFO>
      <ProductTitle>title2</ProductTitle>
      <ContactNum>3</ContactNum>
      <ContactSINum>4</ContactSINum>
   </ProductINFO>
</Productcoll>
```

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)